# Place an angular ui bootstrap dialog at bottom right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've created an Angular UI-bootstrap modal popup (from [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), NOT the default bootstrap one).

Works fine but, of course it's centered by default.  Although for most of my app this is fine, for this particular dialog I need it bottom right.

The entire modal has been put into a directive.  Here's the relevant part, the controller:

```
.controller('FeedbackController', function($scope, $attrs, $modal) {

  var _this = this;

  _this.click = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      windowClass: 'feedback-modal',
      template: '' +
        '<div class="modal-header">' +
        '<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>' +
        '<h3 class="modal-title">Feedback</h3>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label>Please rate your experience</label><br>' +
        '<input type="radio" class="hidden-radio" name="rating" id="happy" ng-model="$parent.rating" ng-value="smile"> ' +
        '<label for="happy">' +
        '<img src="/assets/img/emoji-smile.png" />' +
        '</label>' +
        '<input type="radio" class="hidden-radio" name="rating" id="sad" ng-model="$parent.rating" ng-value="frown"> ' +
        '<label for="sad">' +
        '<img src="/assets/img/emoji-frown.png" />' +
        '</label>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label>Comments</label>' +
        '<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="comment"></textarea>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>' +
        '</div>',
      controller: function($scope, $http, $log, $state, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function() {
          $log.debug('FEEDBACK: ', $state.current.name, $state.params, $scope.comment, $scope.rating);

          $http.post('feedback/url/here', {
            stateName: $state.current.name,
            statParams: $state.params,
            comment: $scope.comment,
            rating: $scope.rating,
            type: $scope.type
          });

          $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
      },
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  };

});
```

You can see I've created a new css class for the modal window, but it seems to refuse to be overridden. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in particular with your question but i'd highly recomend to put your HTML into a separate file and use it with templateUrl instead of template. it would be more clear and readable.

Comment: agreed.  turns out I was targeting the wrong div.  I assigned the class `feedback-modal` but didn't realize I needed to position the div _inside_ of it, `.modal-dialog`.  Works now.

Answer (score 4):

To anyone coming across this:

I was so close.  I correctly passed a windowClass in the open method:

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  windowClass: 'feedback-modal',
```

But I forgot that the *actual* modal is *inside* that:

```
.feedback-modal .modal-dialog {
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
}
```